# Python , facing some confusion with int ()

Tags: python, python-3.x, radix

I was trying out python for the first time, and ended up with a little confusing code. The statement `int("9", 16)` returned 9 , but `int("10", 16)` returned 16. Is it supposed to work so, or did I miss something???

Comment: Research "hexadecimal".

Answer (score 3):

second argument of int function is base for conversion "10" in base 16 is 1*16 + 0*1 = 16. for more details see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is supposed to work like that. `int(number, base)` returns the integer string `number` expressed in the base `base`:

[image]

[image]

You can read the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#int).

Answer (score 0):

between int('9',16) and int('10',16) have int('a',16) - int('f',16).this statement is converts a hexadecimal string to an integer.